# Bypass authentification with curl

Tags: php, curl

I Have two web application, and I want to bypass authentification page with curl and with url.

I make this command :

[in console]

```
curl -u snorby@snorby.org:snorby http://192.168.1.6/login.php
```

[in browser]

```
http://snorby@snorby.org:snorby@192.168.1.6/login.php
```

The first and second command return the login.php

Comment: You go for login.php... so why would it return another url?

Comment: after authentification there is redirection of course

Comment: You need to use this format:

"http : //snorby:snorby@192.168.1.6/login.php"
same for curl - sorry for the bad format. auto url destroyed the link everytime

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://snorby@snorby.org:snorby@192.168.1.6/login.php');`

Answer (score 0):

I have a code here that successfully bypass the authentication of the worksnap website, I want to use there api, but before I can use it, I have to authenticate.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$api_token = 'my api token';

$password = "";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.worksnaps.net/api/projects.xml");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "".$api_token.":".$password.""); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_error($ch);

echo $response;

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: after write this script , it can't redirect me

Comment: that code is just a sample for authentication in a website that requires authentication using cURL.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -d "username=snorby@snorby.org&password=snorby" -i 192.168.1.6/login.php

curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -i 192.168.1.6/index.php
```